# How to disable Hibernate 4 logging into Eclipse console?

Tags: java, eclipse, logging, slf4j, hibernate-4.x

everybody. I am trying to solve the next problem: switch off logging into console when i use hebirnate 4 (**not 3**).
I have next .jars in classpath:
slf4j-api-1.6.1.jar
jboss-logging-3.1.0.GA.jar
slf4j-log4j12-1.5.2.jar

As i said log sentences falls into Eclipse console. It's look like:

> jan 31, 2013 3:58:38 PM org.hibernate.annotations.common.Version
>    INFO: HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations
>   {4.0.1.Final} jan 31, 2013 3:59:09 PM org.hibernate.Version logVersion
>   INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate Core {4.1.9.Final} jan 31, 2013 3:59:12 PM
>   org.hibernate.cfg.Environment  INFO: HHH000205: Loaded
>   properties from resource hibernate.properties: 
>   {hibernate.connection.driver_class=org.h2.Driver,
>   hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect, 
>   hibernate.max_fetch_depth=5, hibernate.format_sql=true,
>   hibernate.generate_statistics=true,  hibernate.connection.username=sa,
>   hibernate.connection.url=jdbc:h2:mem:db1;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;MVCC=TRUE, 
>   hibernate.bytecode.use_reflection_optimizer=false,
>   hibernate.jdbc.batch_versioned_data=true, 
>   hibernate.connection.pool_size=5} jan 31, 2013 4:00:04 PM
>   org.hibernate.cfg.Environment buildBytecodeProvider

I added into src folder file named "slf4j.properties" as i read into different manual and topics including stackoverflow.com.

slf4j.properties contains next:

http://tny.cz/63f0855b

I add link because tags, like ###, in slf4j.properties file make text unreadable.

So... How to switch off logging into console?
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Remove/Comment the following lines

```
log4j.appender.stdout
log4j.appender.stdout.Target
log4j.appender.stdout.layout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern
```

Add the following lines

```
# Direct log messages to a log file
log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.file.File=<Your Path to Log File>/Log.log
log4j.appender.file.MaxFileSize=1MB
log4j.appender.file.MaxBackupIndex=1
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ABSOLUTE} %5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
```

Change the following line

```
log4j.rootLogger=OFF, stdout
```

to

```
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, file
```

Now you shouldn't see logs in Console.

Comment: shazin, thank you. Now my slf4j.properties looks like http://tny.cz/4f2f92f2      =)  But the problem is not solved. Eclipse offers me to go to debug perspective (where i could see Source not found.) and when i push "resume" i see red text in eclipse console =(. also there is not log in the root of "d" drive. Where is my mistake?